# An important thing that can affect / change one's future

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for an adjective which can imply that something is **so important that can change one's destiny.**
I know several words, but I have no idea which one is more associated with one's future. Words like: "decisive", "determining", "vital" etc.

To clarify my meaning, I have made an example. Please consider it and let me know what word would you use there and why?

> - Taylor, I'm your father and want your own good. You know that how important is getting into the university for you. You have to try now to build your future. This is very ................ for you.

I wonder what word would you use here?

---

Added information (clarification):

[Decisive:](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/decisive)

> Strongly affecting how a situation will **progress or end**: 
>   - A decisive victory

[Determining:](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/determining)

> Having the quality of **deciding**. 
>   -  The place of birth is not the determining factor as to whether a person is subject to the security measures.

[Vital:](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/vital)

> - Necessary for the success or continued existence of something; extremely important - **Relating to life.**

According to my definitions, to me these words which based on dictionary definitions were the closest to the word in my question, do not have any direct attachment to **being future / destiny making**; (at least based on my understanding.)

Answer (score 1):

As in:

*This is very **epochal** time for you.*

[TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/epochal)

**epochal**
adj

> - Of or characteristic of an epoch.
> - a. Highly significant or important; momentous:
> - b. Without parallel.

These events are epochal in that they mark the dawn of a new era, a new direction or a new opportunity for one's life.

Comment: But @Ibf while the word "epoch" refers to a long period of time in "history", I think its derived adjective "epochal" has a high tendency towards past, and anything of paramount importance in the past; while I need an adjective more inclined to the future. Please kindly let me know if I'm mistaken or if you have used it in a figurative way.